# what wrong on my Function of link to open new window?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I've tried to create link that can open new window..currently I used

```
Function genLink(req_id)
    genLink = " onclick=""location.href='order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "'  "" "
End function
```

it's work well but just can't make it open link in new window. So i've searched found that it need to be use window.open instead so I do like below.. But it's not work..

```
Function genLink(req_id)
    genLink = " onclick=""window.open='order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "' ,'_blank'  "" "   
End function
```

so could you please tell me what did I do wrong. ?

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` is a javascript function, not a property. Try

```
genLink = " onclick=window.open(""location.href='order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "'  "" )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like too many messing "(double quotes), anyways `window.open` is a function, so it should be as below..

`onclick="window.open('myurl')"`

Comment: actually it was in Function

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
    window.open("order_view.asp?......");
Refer here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
onclick="window.open('order_view.asp?bill_id='+bill_id+'&req_id='+req_id)"
```

Comment: Anandhakumar has simply coded the answer purely for inclusion into an HTML tag. Simply change it slightly to this: `genLink = "onclick=""window.open('order_view.asp?bill_id=" & bill_id & "&req_id='+req_id)"""`