# How to create a function to generate link by opening new window

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I've tried to create function of link that can open new window..currently I used

```
Function genLink(req_id)
    genLink = " onclick=""location.href='order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "'  "" "
End function
```

it's work but not open new window for me ..

So i've searched found that it need to be use window.open instead so I do like below.. But it's not work..

```
Function genLink(req_id)
    genLink = " onclick=""window.open='order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "' ,'_blank'  "" "   
End function
```

so could you please tell me what did I do wrong. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what wrong on my Function of link to open new window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323525/what-wrong-on-my-function-of-link-to-open-new-window)

Comment: Alxan, practically everyone in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323525/what-wrong-on-my-function-of-link-to-open-new-window) answered succinctly. You need to go through the answers and see why they don't work for you. Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: well.. i have posted on that but i might not make it clear that I need it to work in Function not just in ordinary way. So people give me wrong answer and when I tried to edit my question. It too late... most people think my question have a lot of answers already and nobody came out to help me fix this. So that's why i have to re-post it. And if i won't , I will never get the right answer like the one below.

Comment: You should have edited that question and clarified it. There was all sorts of information, including a link to the function itself, that you could have used.

Comment: I did... and still didn't get answer. That's why i did this.. please try to understand. I wouldn't do this if I have the other way. If i don't do this in no time my post will be way down behind and I would not be able to get the answer. What will you do if you desperate for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
genLink = " onclick=""window.open('order_view.asp?bill_id=" & req_id & "' , null, '_blank'  )"" "
```

window.open() is a method, and the 2nd param it's the name.

*window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)*

Comment: it's work!.. really thank you . I wouldn't be able to achieve this without your help . thank you very much..

Comment: Great! Based on Paul's comment, maybe You should delete your other question to avoid duplicates